# Joule-Kelvin coefficent what does $p$ and $T$ represent?

Tags: thermodynamics

In the Joule-Kelvin expansion we take a gas at one pressure $p_1$ and throttle it through a valve to another pressure $p_2$ where these two pressures are taken to be constant. The Joule-Kelvin coefficient is given by: 
$$\mu_{JK} = \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial p}\right)_H$$
So what temperature does $T$ represent and what pressure does $p$ represent?

Comment: May you explain the question in more details? Because, obviously $T$ represents the temperature of the system (gas) at each moment and $P$ represents the pressure of the system (gas) at each moment.

Answer (score 1):

It represents the rate of change of the temperature by a small increment (although in practice in this process the increment is always negative) of pressure. If you want to go from a pressure $p_1$ to a pressure $p_2$, then the change in temperature will be

$$
\int_{p1}^{p2}  \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial p}\right)_H \mathrm{d}p
$$

Notice this is correct because the enthalpy $H$ is constant during the process, so the more general expression $\mathrm{d}H = C_{\mathrm{p}}\mathrm{d}T  + V\left(1-T\alpha\right) \mathrm{d}P$ reduces to $0 = C_{\mathrm{p}}\mathrm{d}T  + V\left(1-T\alpha\right) \mathrm{d}P$.