# Show that the Joule-Kelvin coefficient is equal to zero when the fluid is an ideal gas?

Tags: thermodynamics

The Joule-Kelvin coefficient is given by:

$$μ_{JK}≡(\frac{∂T}{∂P})_H=\frac{1}{C_P}  (T(\frac{∂V}{∂T})_P-V)$$

Where the Ideal gas equation with, $n = 1$ is:

$$\frac{V}{T} = \frac{R}{P}$$

I also know the following to be true, however I'm not sure about how to derive it:

$$(\frac{∂V}{∂T})_P=\frac{V}{T}$$

Comment: If $R$ and $P$ are constant, then that derivative is not zero.   But $P$ is not constant.

Comment: Related:  http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/222132/5739

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on my part, P is constant for the partial derivative now.

Comment: I've just managed to solve it, I'll edit the question and then answer it properly later